# Geometrical meaning of integrating a surface over one of its variable support

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying for Statistic, where I found the formula for the marginal pdf $f(x)$ of a bivariate distribution is equal to the integration of the bivariate pdf over the support of the other variable, i.e:

$f(x)=\int_{y\in S} f(x,y)$, where S is the support of y.

As I understand, $f(x,y)$ is a three-dimensional surface (which, for heuristic purposes, I would call a "mountain"). Thus I guess that the integration over one of its variable would be taking a two-dimensional "slice" out of it? For example, does integrate over the support of $y$ means to stand on the side of the "mountain" from the y-axis and take a 2-D picture of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For any given $x_0$ the integral $f(x_0) = \int_{y\in S} f(x_0,y) dy$ means you slice the mountain at the plane $x=x_0$.  Now the cross-section is the function $g(y) = f(x_0,y)$, you measure the area of the cross section via the integral $\int g(y) dy$, and that area is $f(x_0)$.

Taking a picture from the side would just find something like max.

---

UPDATE: Here's an example where the support for $y$ depends on $x$:

- $f(x,y) = 2$ in the support $0 < y < x < 1$.

The support is a triangle, and $f$ is constant $=2$ within that triangle (and of course $0$ outside the triangle) so $f(x,y)$ is a triangular "plateau".  We have:

$$f(x) = \int_0^x 2\ dy = [2y]^x_0 = 2x$$

so $f(x)$ is a rising line, describing perfectly how the cross sectional area varies as a function of $x$.  Note that $f(x)$, as a curve, does not fit anywhere w.r.t. the triangular plateau.

Comment: Thank you very much. But if the support of $y$ is dependent on $x$, say 0<y<x, then what would the geometric meaning of the curve $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)$ as a function of $x$ be?

Comment: In the context of probability/statistics, the pdf is $\ge 0$ everywhere and the support merely indicates that the pdf $\equiv 0$ _outside_ the support.  Honestly you can imagine integrating over the whole real line $(-\infty, +\infty)$ but just be careful that anywhere outside the support you use $g(y) = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry I think there is a little misunderstanding. Say for example I have the curve $x^2+y^2$ (which looks like an upside down mat here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%5E2%2By%5E2). If I integrate this surface from 0 to $x$ w.r.t $y$, I get the curve $4x^3/3$. My question is where is the location of this curve on the "upside down mat" then?

Comment: $f(x) = \int_0^x (x^2 + y^2) dy = 4x^3 / 3$ and this curve is not shown anywhere on the "upside down mat".  What's the problem?  Remember $f(x)$ describes how the "cross-section area" changes as a function of $x$, so it does not necessarily have anything to do with curves _on_ the mountain _surface_ at all.